# How to custom sort in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I just started learning django.

I found out that to sort data from the database we can use the `.order_by()` method, passing the sorting keys as parameters.

Suppose I don't want to use this built in sort method: How can I specify my own sorting algorithm (maybe insert sort or something) ?

Comment: `order_by()` is ultimately using the `ORDER BY` clause of DB and t's not a `python` sorting method/function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.order_by()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) generates a `ORDER BY` clause in the underlying `SQL` statement that is generated by Django.

As far as I know, you cannot change this behaviour. And you cannot specify your own sort function, since `.order_by()` is not executed at the Python level but at the database level.

Comment: Okay Got it.  So if I have to sort in another way then I have to get all data from database and then sort it accordingly.

Comment: Correct. But database sorting (if there are indexes) is usually a lot faster than sorting in python.